# Unable to set timer using javascript for different window instances?

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a page which opens a popup window, the popup creates google map depending on querystring parameters by processing the data on page and after creating the map it saves using webmethod/ajax to specified location and popup gets closed automatically using settimeout function.

This works only for single request/single popup window.

I have many rows say 10 rows i open the popup for each row and want to close using timer(only after successfully creating/saving the img).

**MainPage.aspx**

```
//someloop here for iterating rows
   foreach(..)
     {
       CallMap(packageid, latitudelangitude);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
   int i = 1;
    protected void CallMap(string packageid, string latitudelangitude)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:58715/mymap.aspx?pkg=" + packageid + "&data=" + latitudelangitude;// +"&t=" + i;
        string fullURL = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'height=600,width=1000,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,titlebar=no' );";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
   "newWindow" + i++, String.Format("<script>" + fullURL + "</script>", string.Empty));
   }
```

**mymap.aspx**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        initialize();
       setInterval(function () { window.close() }, 2000);
    });
```

*Here, the timer is getting timeout for all 10 windows at the same time. how to reset different timer for different window instance of same page?*

Comment: did you try with var windowObjectReference = window.open(...) ? then you could call windowObjectReference.close()

Comment: how to use it in c#?

Comment: still same issue...any other way???

Comment: don't now why some people just go on negative marking the post??? when they don't understand the problem or else no solution with them. Atleast negative marker person should specify the REASON...as comment to the post as per stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 0):

The timer closes windows in the same time because of

```
setInterval(function () { window.close() }, 2000);
```

As all windows opened using same startup script `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`, they will be opened in same time and closed in same interval which is 2000 ms. Depends on your requirements, you either need to open windows differently or close them on another event. Currently, your requirement of

> want to close using timer(only after successfully creating/saving the img).

seems not valid as there no trigger in the presented code for "successfully creating/saving the img".

Comment: what do you mean by 'need to open window differently'???? 
i am opening same webpage with different multiple instances as popup...

Comment: You are "opening same webpage with different multiple instances" in same time, all instances have same script with `window.close` in 2000 ms - so why do you expect other result than closing all windows in same time?

Comment: becoz I want to close the window autimatically after 2secs for each window SEPARATELY as rending the google map and saving the image in required size need some time...so that each window will get enough time to process the image and save in specified size using binary...
where as in current situation all window timeout at the same time and image is not getting saved properly...

Comment: Again, my understanding on your code: 1) `RegisterStartupScript` opens all windows in *same time* 2) `$(document).ready` occurs for all windows in *same time* 3) timeout to close for all windows is *same* - 2000 ms. This is why all windows will be closed in the same time. `$(document).ready` occurs without waiting for google map loads, depends on your needs, you might need to use `$(window).load` that fires after the document.ready. To debug, instead of `window.close()` put an alert and see when it will show a message - before your map is ready, or after that.